# Why is Stack Overflow's reputation tally wrong?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, up-votes

According to the Stack Overflow FAQ, an accepted answer gets +15 and an upvoted answer is +10. So why did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965734/maven-native-dependences-in-eclipse/11966360#11966360) get a total of +15, even though the answer is accepted and voted up?

Is there any error in Stack Overflow engine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11965734/timeline) the answer was upvoted on August 15th, then accepted on August 20th.

Your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210779/sai-ye-yan-naing-aye?tab=reputation) shows both these point increases on their respective dates, you didn't miss any points:

[image: reputation tab with highlighted reputation increases]

Comment: [Very true](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl33g.png) :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Thank you, I'll stea^Wborrow that nice image link if you don't mind.. :-P

Comment: Hey share some rep! ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: you have plenty, me thinks. :-P